# CORS error when using googleapi JWT on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, google-analytics-api

I am trying to authorize using JWT with googleapis, to be able to access analytics data, but I am geeting

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 400 ()

Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

When I run this code.

```
import google from 'googleapis'
const key = require('../../../static/key.json')

export const GA = {
  methods: {
    getVisits () {
      var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] // an array of auth scopes
      )

      jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          // return
        } else {
          console.log('Successfully connected!')
        }
       })
    }
  }

}
```

I am trying to access the data using a serviceaccount which is set up on the project in developer console.

I cannot see what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling the script in my server.js script. My bad!